# Using beautifulsoup to parse more than one website

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, beautifulsoup, urllib2

Thanks to the awesome people on this forum, I have successfully made a working script to pull a podcast from a site. The following code works fine, I just need to pull the image (thumbnail) from the next bit of code rather than the link in the 'soup.find_all' command:

```
def get_playable_podcast(soup):
    """
    @param: parsed html page            
    """
    subjects = []

    for content in soup.find_all('item'):

        try:        
            link = content.find('enclosure')
            link = link.get('url')
            print "\n\nLink: ", link

            title = content.find('title')
            title = title.get_text()

            desc = content.find('itunes:subtitle')
            desc = desc.get_text()

            thumbnail = content.find('itunes:image')
            thumbnail = thumbnail.get('href')

        except AttributeError:
            continue

    item = {
            'url': link,
            'title': title,
            'desc': desc,
            'thumbnail': thumbnail
    }

    subjects.append(item) 

return subjects

def compile_playable_podcast(playable_podcast):
"""
@para: list containing dict of key/values pairs for playable podcasts
"""
items = []

for podcast in playable_podcast:
    items.append({
        'label': podcast['title'],
        'path': podcast['url'],
        'info': podcast['desc'],
        'is_playable': True,})

return items
```

The following code I have literally downloads the image, I need to basically combine it into the above code and create references for the image rather than downloading so it can be ultimately incorporated in the 'subjects.append' section. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
resp = requests.get("https://thisiscriminal.com/wp-json/criminal/v1/episodes?posts=1000000&page=1").json()
df = pd.DataFrame(resp['posts'], columns=['image'])
df['image'] = df['image'].apply(pd.Series)['large'].replace({'"': '\'','""': '\'','"""': '\'' }, regex=True)
Regex_Pattern = r"([^\/]+$)"

        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            match = re.findall(Regex_Pattern, row['image'])
            myfilename = ''.join(match)
            print(row['image'])
            print(myfilename)
            urllib.urlretrieve(row['image'], myfilename)
```

Comment: What is the URL you use to get `soup` for your `get_playable_podcast()` function?

Comment: I don't understand. You already have thumbnail in the top section. What isn't working with that?

Comment: @MartinEvans Thanks for the reply. The link is: http://feeds.thisiscriminal.com/CriminalShow
which is the generic image, but the actual thumbnail needs to be parsed with the 2nd it of code from:
https://thisiscriminal.com/wp-json/criminal/v1/episodes?posts=1000000&page=1

Obviously the latter is javascript and therefore the need for the dataframe code

Comment: @QHarr The thumbnail does work yes, but it's a generic one. The actual image needs to be pulled from another link which is a bit tricker hence the code to pull a json dataframe from the 2nd link (just posted in another comment)